# Sennheiser mke 2 and ew100 g3= cable noise. Any ideas why?

Tags: noise, cable, lavalier, sennheiser

Just upgraded my me2 to an MKE2. Used with g3 wireless. The cable on the new MKE2 has the blue (attenuator or whatever that is with the serial #).  I read that the blue version had more shielding for the newer digital transmitters, which my system is not. 
There is quite a bit of cable noise being picked up by the MKE2. It’s very annoying.  If I rub my finger up and down the cable, even near the transmitter, I get constant sound picked up.
It’s almost unusable. 
Any idea what is going on and how to fix this issue?  The me2 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This effect is known as 'microphonic' which is ironic in that the device that is being 'microphonic' is actually a microphone itself. Having said that, 'microphonic' normally refers to a device or component that isn't supposed to be a microphone - acting like one.

Googling around a bit, this is a common problem with lavaliers, however this sounds a little bit more serious than your run-of-the-mill handling noise.

I suggest you consider placing a cable loop behind the mic clip in order to isolate any handling noise reaching the capsule.

Also, don't rub the cable. If this is what is making the noise, then stop doing it. It's not normal operational activity when using a lavalier. Lavaliers are designed to be placed either in a hidden position or in a visible position, then left alone. Minimise handling or clothing noise through using tried and trusted location sound techniques for lav placement.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. When making the loop you referred to, must the wires touch?  I would assume that is the entire point. Thanks again

Comment: The point of the loop is to provide a level of strain relief during the placement. This video may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX5r4WMWwHc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MKE2's have particularly bad cable noise.  It's a really unfortunate trade off, as for the price point, MKE2's sound quality is generally higher than its equivalent competitors, yet you will find cheaper microphones with much less cable noise (as you've noticed with the old ME2).

On the other extreme side, like any microphone, It's built to a price point.  If you compare it to something like a DPA 4061, which is around 2-3x the price, the cable noise is exponentially less.

So unfortunately that is just the way MKE2's are.  If you want to try and reduce noise, its more about cable management.  Get yourself some medical / sports tapes from your local chemist, and ensure the cable is controlled on the persons body or clothing to minimised cable rub.